# How to pass a value to getServerSideProps?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Using nextjs, I have state that contains the users JWT, This needs to be passed into the request in getServerSideProps.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {

  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/publics')
  const data = await res.json()
  const theData = data[ctx.query.id - 1]

  return {
    props: {data: theData}, 
  }
}
```

How can i pass the JWT here?

Comment: How is the JWT stored? Is it in a cookie?

Comment: its currently just in the app state

Comment: If you store the JWT in cookie. You can acquire it by using `ctx.req.header.cookie`.

Comment: That  makes sense... Is there any other way than a cookie though? I dont really like using them and would like to use a bearer token if possible